# Have function called based on default dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to redirect a customer to another page using Javascript, if a country other than the US is chosen in a dropdown field. I got it to work, but registered guests have their country default in the dropdown and the function doesn't get called unless the user switches it.

**This is the code as it stands now**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var una = "ok";
    $("#shipping-country").change(function(event){                   
    if(($("#shipping-country").val() != "US") &&(una=="ok")){
            iCheckout.insertForm();
        $("#iCheckoutForm").submit();
    }

});
});
```

How can I rewrite this to have it redirect if a country other than the US is already chosen by default?

Comment: for registered guests do you want to choose their country as a default value in dropdown and redirect them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to check whether their default value is not the US on page load as well as when the value of the dropdown changes?

I'd refactor it a bit:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var una = "ok";
    var checkIfUS = function() {
        if(($("#shipping-country").val() != "US") &&(una=="ok")){
            iCheckout.insertForm();
            $("#iCheckoutForm").submit();
        }
    };

    checkIfUS(); // check if it should redirect after dom load

    $("#shipping-country").change(function(event){                   
        checkIfUS(); // check if it should redirect on form change
    });
});
```

Alternatively, if you're populating the dropdown with javascript, you can add checkIfUS() as a callback to whatever populates the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var una = "ok";

    $("#shipping-country").change(function(event){                   
        if(($("#shipping-country").val() != "US") &&(una=="ok")){
                iCheckout.insertForm();
            $("#iCheckoutForm").submit();
        }

    });

    if ($("#shipping-country").val() != 'US') {
        // your redirect code here
        window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }
});
```

Comment: I would like to give you rep points, but need over 15 to do so. 

Thanks!